# Status bar of iOS app completely transparant instead of translucent (using WKWebView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I'm currently writing my first iOS app in Swift, via Xcode. I have used the WKWebview to load our responsive website.

It's very basic, but works well. The only problem is that the status bar (with the time and battery information) is completely transparent. I'd like to make this translucent (or even completely solid if necessary).

Our website has a fixed top menu, so the website will scroll underneath that and is then fully visible again 'underneath' the time and battery info, which looks very weird.

No matter what I have tried, with setting background colors, opacity, etc., the top part stays completely transparent.

Thank you for your answers.

Edit: For anyone interested in this as well, I figured out to get a background color to the status bar, by adding this code to the AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
   statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.95)
}
```

This doesn't give the "frosted glass" effect unfortunately however, so I'm still searching for a better alternative.

Comment: Check your constraints for the webview, it might be set with superview, ensure the top constraint is added to the safe area

Comment: @GoodSp33d Thank you for the feedback. I've re-set the constraints, but the problem keeps persisting. The WKWebView automatically overflows outside of its boundaries (I think Apple calls this "context"). I don't mind that behavior, as long as I can make the status bar less transparent, like for example with the frosted glass effect.

Comment: have you found a solution?